# What is this robot story?

Tags: story-identification, robots

I remember reading some robot stories years ago, and am trying to track down the stories to read again. Initially I though they must be Asimov stories, but I can find no Asimov story that has what I remember.

The story (or stories) is about a boy that has a robot. I part of the story the robot has only black and white vision, but someone(I forget) replaces its with a new tube, so that the robot see now see in color. The boy is disappointed as he wanted to get the tube for the robot, as soon as he had enough money saved.

In another part of the story, the robot is on his own and Is being tracked down,
he is going to "Charge" (Attack) but is turned off by a switch, before he attacks. The comment is that the company says they have never seen such devotion in a robot for its owner. Story may have "Marsport" or "Marspoint" in the story.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: If you can remember anything else, that would be really helpful. Lots of science fiction stories involve robots.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting mixed up with [I'm In Marsport Without Hilda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_in_Marsport_Without_Hilda) which is an Asimov story but doesn't match any part of your description

Comment: The quote about someone never having seen such devotion is very reminiscent of Star Wars; [but I've never seen such devotion in a droid before](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/f858d516-6897-423b-9a91-f1e2402521f6)

Comment: That bit about improving the robot's vision with the color tube sounds *vaguely familiar,* but I can't say where I ran across it. (I'm pretty sure it did not happen in any of Isaac Asimov's robot stories.)

Comment: "I can't see colors."

"Your refractor bulb is for black and white?"

"Yes."
That's Marsport, but Mars City is something different. 

The third part of the Complex is the big passenger spaceport called Marspoint
I tried to charge, but I was too late. He snapped the switch, and it was the end of
me.

Answer (score 15):

I believe you are referring to the juvenile novel [The Runaway Robot](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/52666.The_Runaway_Robot).  (1965) published with Lester del Rey's byline, but was actually ghost-written by Paul W. Fairman based on an outline by del Rey.

The giveaway was the color vision. In Runaway Robot, the robot get color-sensing eyes, and springs that as a surprise on the kid who's his best friend "Say, Paul, that's a nice red shirt you're wearing this morning."

The other part that matches is that the robot is shutoff at one point trying to 'fake' that he is a 'rogue' robot. The police/law enforcement/mp, doesn't believe Rex is truly rogue and simply walks up and shuts him off rather than destroying him via ray blaster or some such type weapon. That part is on Mars which matches what you remember.

You may also remember another scene in which the robot,  Rex, plays chess with the spaceship captain helping him reach Paul (after having stowed away). No surprise, Rex beats the pants off the captain who mutters something along the line, "Who says they're going to invent robots that take over the solar system.  They already have!"

Some other covers exist [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059002261X) if that helps ring a bell.

Hope this helps.

> •The robot named Rex had been bought as a companion for Paul when the Simpsons decided to pioneer on Ganymede, a moon of Jupiter...a rough, dangerous satellite where a small boy needed a strong, intelligent robot to protect him. By the time Paul is sixteen, they are inseparable. Robots, of course, have a personality leeway that gives each one a certain individuality within its pattered capacities — and Rex had a wonderful personality, with a logic quotient that allowed him to reason. But when the Simpson family is ordered back to Earth and Paul refuses to part with Rex, the robot plans to stow away on a spaceship to Earth — no easy feat, even for a robot with Rex's abilities. Thrilling chases in skimmers, through spaceports, and over the deserts of Mars are just the start of the problems for The Runaway Robot!

Comment: Thats it ! Thank You Beichst. Found a pdf Below are some Excerpts. I am pround that I remebered so much from when I was a kid!

Comment: Excellent!  Glad I was able to help you find this. You are correct. Your memory and listing of items was great. Very distinctive in helping identify the story.

Comment: @Slickfix  If this is the correct answer, could you accept it (green checkmark) so that we could see that at a glance?  As is, we have to read the comments to see that this is what you wanted.